# Polynomial raised to the $4^{\text{th}}$ power. Why does it correspond to the below sum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, summation

Let us start from the following function:
$$\Delta_j(t)=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2^j-1}}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)\tag{1}$$
where $j\geq0$ arbitrarily fixed, $k=0,1,\ldots,2^j-1$,
$G_i\sim\mathbb{N}\left(0,1\right)$ and $S_i:t\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is a function I am not going to exactly define here (out of scope). 
Given the specific form of $S_i$, one already knows that, for $k\neq l$, $S_{2^j+k}\cdot S_{2^j+l}=0$ (give it for granted). I am then told that:
$$|\Delta_j(t)|^4=\sum_{k,l,p,q=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}G_{2^j+l}G_{2^j+p}G_{2^j+q}S_{2^j+k}(t)S_{2^j+l}(t)S_{2^j+p}(t)S_{2^j+q}(t)\tag{2}$$
$$=\sum_{k}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}^4|S_{2^j+k}(t)|^4\tag{3}$$


What I cannot understand is why $(1)$ - in absolute value - raised to the $4^{\text{th}}$ power yields $(2)$, while $(3)$ is clear to me.

---

Why is $(2)$ true? Could you please give me some reference/hint for that fact?

Comment: Should there not be $| |$ signs on the RHS of (2)?

Comment: I was thinking about that as well, but on my reference there are not $||$ signs, maybe it could be a typo (?) Apart from that, I cannot even superficially understand why $(2)$ holds true anyway @ancientmathematician

Comment: OK, try again. The LHS of (2) is of the form $|A|^4$ and $|A|^4=A^4$. So take the $4$-th powers of (1) and you have (2) at once. Now use your orthogonality condition and you'll get (3) without the modulus signs. But the modulus of a 4th power is itself, so we're done.

Comment: My problem (silly, I'm sure) is that I cannot understand why the $4^{\text{th}}$ power of $(1)$ corresponds to $(2)$. Could you please give me a reference for the fourth power of a polynomial? @ancientmathematician

Comment: Hint: $(\sum_{i=1}^M a_i)^2=(\sum_{i=1}^M a_i)(\sum_{j=1}^M a_j)=\sum_{i,j=1}^M a_i a_j$. [Part of your problem I suspect is that the simple structure of this is lost in the  noise of the elaborate notation/]

Comment: So, I consider $\sum_{i=1}^M a_i=\sum_{k=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)$. Then, $$\big(\sum_{k=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)\big)^2=\big(\sum_{k=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)\big)\big(\sum_{l=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+l}S_{2^j+l}(t)\big)=\sum_{k,l=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)G_{2^j+l}S_{2^j+l}(t)$$
**[continue]**

Comment: **[continue]** Finally, $$\big(\big(\sum_{k=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)\big)^2\big)^2=\big(\sum_{k=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)\big)^4=\big(\sum_{k,l=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)G_{2^j+l}S_{2^j+l}(t)\big)\big(\sum_{p,q=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+p}S_{2^j+p}(t)G_{2^j+q}S_{2^j+q}(t)\big)=\sum_{k,l,p,q=0}^{2^j-1}G_{2^j+k}S_{2^j+k}(t)G_{2^j+l}S_{2^j+l}(t)G_{2^j+p}S_{2^j+p}(t)G_{2^j+q}S_{2^j+q}(t)$$ Right, @ancientmathematician?

Comment: That would do nicely..

Comment: If you wish, you could write your Hint as an answer to my question and I would be very glad to award it

Comment: If you want to write it up yourself that's fine by me.